# cannot bind port 3306 while "netstat" says 3306 is available?

Tags: mysql, port

Messages in mysqld.log:

```
140519 19:21:53 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
140519 19:21:53 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
140519 19:21:53 [ERROR] Aborting
```

while

```
netstat -nlp |grep 3306
```

shows no process is using this port, but mysqld fail with binding address error.

---

The whole story is:

I slipped up when searching mysql on our server and installed with

```
yum -y install mysql mysql-server
```

and then found mysql cannot start with the error above.

I'm not sure whether the duplicated installation of mysql cause this problem. I've also tried to bind 3306 in httpd, getting the same error.

So it seems that the ports management related function comes into a inconsistent state, or a state that "netstat" cannot figure out?

May I ask how does the system check whether a port is in use when a bind request arrive?

---

Below is the content of my my.cnf. It was left unmodified.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
port=3306
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
lower_case_table_names=1
max_connections=13000

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
wait_timeout = 1814400
```

---

Thanks to @favoretti : 
I've started the service by setting `bind-address = <myip>  port = 3306`
but,

`bind-address = 0.0.0.0  port = 3306` doesn't work

while `bind-address = 0.0.0.0  port = 3307` works well.

(`0.0.0.0` is the default value of `bind-address`)

Comment: What's your `bind-address` in `my.cnf`?

Comment: @favoretti Sorry for replying late. I've added my.cnf in the post.

Comment: Your title isn't correct. 'netstat' hasn't said the port 'is available'. It just hasn't printed anything about the port being in use. It isn't the same thing.

Comment: @EJP: Essentially it _is_ the same thing.

Comment: Would it help if you remove the `port` directive from your config and add `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to begin with? If that works, you can replace `127.0.0.1` with the address of your box if you want to accept connections over TCP from other servers.

Comment: @favoretti: It **dose** work! Brilliant! So what's the devil behind?

Comment: Well, I guess it tries to bind to some address it can't and in the end actually fails to start. :)

Comment: @favoretti, yeah, it did say that it cannot bind the specified address. What is the possible case that no process can bind `0.0.0.0:<some_port>` while `netstat` cannot find the record? (I've add new infos in the post above. I think you can edit you reply above as an 'answer' so that I can accept it :) )

Comment: Well, not sure, maybe some apparmor or something like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting as answer as requested.

Would it help if you remove the `port` directive from your config and add `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to begin with? If that works, you can replace 127.0.0.1 with the address of your box if you want to accept connections over TCP from other servers.

Basically, specify a bind address by hand.

Comment: can you help on this http://serverfault.com/questions/735699/cannot-bind-a-port-altough-listen